# Perimeters and Properties of Strings by Transformations

Tags: geometry

I've been thinking for a while about strings, and I've been wondering if a method exists to 'straighten' a string. To straighten a string, you take the starting point (at the origin) and consider it a holding point. Then take the endpoint and pull it horizontally in the x-direction. Imagine doing this until the whole string is centered on the x-axis.

-How would you calculate the rate at which the string's original position changes relative to the x and y axes (related rates)?

-If the string has multiple maxima and minima, and you straighten this string, how do these curves change? Does it become a physics problem?

-How would you express this problem using linear algebra?

-How would you use such a method in multiple dimensions?

-And of course, how would you find the perimeter of the string?

Comment: It sounds to me like a physics problem, at least initially.  We need to model how the force pulling one end along the $x$-axis is transmitted along the string.  Then I suppose it become a problem in ODE, but I don't really know.

Comment: Is this string a light string or a heavy string?

Comment: I think it is best to describe it as a perfect string, which could mean that it is a medium string.