# How does shifting a root of a quadratic function affect the distance from the vertex to the $x$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a curve with a finite length on a plane, and it has two integer zeros (consider it a quadratic), and I shift the greater zero value horizontally to the right, how will the distance of the vertex from the x-axis decrease relative to its starting position?

Comment: How do you shift just one zero to the right while leaving the other fixed? There is more than one way to do this. One way leaves the vertex the same distance from the $x$ axis, another increases the distance, and if you want to you can even decrease the distance.

Comment: If the curve is quadratic, the vertex will align with the x value half-way between the two roots.

Comment: Related to earlier question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903495/perimeters-and-properties-of-strings-by-transformations